# Java: Nested Tree Structure

Tags: java, treeview, directory-structure, jlist

I am looking for a way to create a nested tree structure in my GUI. I have a few "boxes" that have items in them. I would like the boxes to be collapsed but expanded when clicked on, like the way folders are navigated on the sidebar. The first way I considered was treating the "boxes" as JList, with the items in each box stored in a nested JList. This seems like a very complicated and poor way of doing it. It also prevents the boxes from being collapsible without extensive modifications to the actionlistener. I was hoping someone might know of an API perhaps for displaying file navigation that might be used here.

Comment: @jon clements, don't forget to delete the accepted answer since it provides the same link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [JTree](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html).  There is a [tutorial on using JTree](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/Tree.htm).